# Spring social NoSuchMethodError SocialAuthenticationFilter.getFilterProcessesUrl()

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I use spring security login. Now I'm trying to add spring social facebook login,  but I get many error information.

First, when I try to use the same method like [spring social guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/), I can't `@Autowired private Facebook facebook`

I found a solution

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository repository) {
    Connection<Facebook> connection = repository
            .findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
    return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
}
```

Next, I get the error "cannot find bean". I have to add:

```
 @Bean
 public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
 Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
 .getAuthentication();
 if (authentication == null) {
 throw new IllegalStateException(
 "Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
 }
 return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(
 authentication.getName());
 }

@Bean
public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();

     registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookid,
                facebookSecure));

    return registry;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationNameUserIdSource authenticationNameUserIdSource(){
    return new  AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
}


@Bean
public ConnectController connectController(
        ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator,
        ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    return new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator,
            connectionRepository);
}

@Bean
public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
    return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource,
            connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
}
```

After that, I have other issue `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.getFilterProcessesUrl()Ljava/lang/String;`

```
@Bean
  public SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator socialAuthenticationServiceLocator() {
    SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry registry = new SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry();
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookid,
            facebookSecure));
    return registry;
}

     @Bean
 public SocialAuthenticationFilter socialAuthenticationFilter()
 throws Exception {
 SocialAuthenticationFilter filter = new SocialAuthenticationFilter(
 authenticationManager(), authenticationNameUserIdSource(),
 usersConnectionRepository(), socialAuthenticationServiceLocator());
 filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
 filter.setSignupUrl("/signup");
 filter.setConnectionAddedRedirectUrl("/home");
 filter.setPostLoginUrl("/home"); // always open account profile
 // page after login
 // filter.setRememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
 return filter;
 }
```

but always is the same.

This is my http configuration

```
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home", "/css/**", "/**/*.css*", "/", "/signup",
                    "/facebook", "/signup.xhtml").permitAll().anyRequest()
               .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").failureUrl("/login")

            .permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
```

And controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String loginPage() {
 return "redirect:/login/authenticate/connect/facebook";

 }
```

I did a whole [tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/). Next, I removed `SocialConfigurer` implementation and created the same (not `@Override`, only `@Bean`) [social documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/).

'Normal login '(spring security) works fine, but I can't configure spring social with spring security. I use `JSF` and `.XHTML` files.

Maybe someone knows where I make the mistakes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Likely a version conflict. Which versions are you using?

Comment: facebook social I use `<version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>` but in aplication I use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` maybe this is a problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Spring Security removed getFilterProcessesUrl() in Spring Security 4.0.0.RC1 (it was marked as deprecated anyways).

It seems that other project filters have not been updated?

Try rolling back to 4.0.0.M2 or use the 3.2 train.

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that spring security 4 will not accept spring social 1.1.0. Please upgrade all spring social dependencies(config, core, security and web) to 1.1.2.RELEASE. You can leave your spring social Facebook to 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in my comment, you have the wrong version of some library. My intelligent guess is that version of *Spring Security* is wrong. From what I can find, you should use a version in the **3.2.x** series (for example 3.2.5) of Spring Security.

Comment: @luprogrammer Wrong version of Spring Security, you see? Change `4.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT` to `3.2.5`.

Comment: When I change to `4.0.0.RC1` I have the same issue, but now I'm using `@EnableSocial` after that I can redirect to facebook login but now I have other problem [anonymusUser] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236063/spring-social-facebook-login-inserts-anonymoususer-in-database/28245733#28245733)

Comment: @luprogrammer Unless you have a special reason, you should not use anything but `RELEASE` versions.

Comment: When I change to `4.0.0.M2`  => `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/OrderProvider` but I Have `spring-security-core` and `spring-core`

Comment: @luprogrammer `Mx` = milestone, `RC` = release candidate, these are development versions and not intended to be included in regular projects!

Comment: I heard about I musn't combain Spring framework 4 with spring security 3.x

Comment: I change to spring security 3.2.5 I have to add more another dependencys but after change I can,t compile project `IllegalStateException: SpringSocialConfigurer depends on org.springframework.social.security.SocialUserDetailsService. No single bean of that type found in application context`I implements this service only [once] (http://paste.ofcode.org/9HGDZN3FBuqchSEQsff8V4) this problem is when I use `httpConfigure...  .and().apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer())`  [pom.xml] (http://paste.ofcode.org/LAUjhVmkXgNkDr2Cz7ZzE)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using version 1.1.4.

this is solved in spring-social-security 1.1.4.RELEASE (or perhaps some version before).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social