# Error processing request spring social

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I'm trying use spring social in my web app. I'm using [configuration](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/)but alweys get Error processing request

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter.getFilterProcessesUrl()Ljava/lang/String;`

This [solution](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/123476-how-to-use-org-springframework-social-security-socialauthenti-cationfilter) doesn't work in my case.

Thanks for help

Comment: This [solution](https://www.jiwhiz.com/#/blogs/50f4f033e4b04d4d302ba03a) also doesn't work

Comment: This is my second  [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070088/spring-social-nosuchmethoderror-socialauthenticationfilter-getfilterprocessesurl)

Comment: Please don't post duplicates.

Comment: Ok. tomorrow I will read again, but Could you tell me why ? Maybe You show me where I make the biggest mistake ?

Comment: Ok sorry can I finish this issue here ?

Comment: Only add thats I use JSF and xhtml no jsp like the tutorial. @Jame Wite if you can answer me why my configuration is terribly wrong

Comment: @ Jamie White why did you remove your answer. It was a very helpfully example

Comment: Please notice that spring security 4 will not accept spring social 1.1.0. Please upgrade all spring social dependencies(config, core, security and web) to 1.1.2.RELEASE. You can leave your spring social Facebook to 1.1.0.  Also don't post duplicates but try to create a more elaborate question with all the essential code pieces in it.