# Spring Social Facebook Login inserts anonymousUser in database

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-social

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjsWJ.png

UserConnection table gets populated by anonymousUser after successful authentication by Facebook. What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ProviderSignInController, override its methods, used SignInUtils to add the user.